# Clear definition of coroutines dispatcher in kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to migrate from RxJava to coroutines for my current projects. So I was going through the official doc and I came across `Dispatchers`. According to the official document they define Dispatchers as:

> Coroutine context includes a coroutine dispatcher (see
>   CoroutineDispatcher) that determines what thread or threads the
>   corresponding coroutine uses for its execution. Coroutine dispatcher
>   can confine coroutine execution to a specific thread, dispatch it to a
>   thread pool, or let it run unconfined.

What do they mean by thread pool? Are `Dispatchers.IO` or `Dispatchers.Default` different threads? I am confused by the term thread here. Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

They are similar to Schedulers.io(), Schedulers.computation(), Schedulers.newThread() and abstracts thread pools.

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines and threads are different concepts. The same holds for dispatchers. Dispatchers are more like executors which schedule work. This work runs on threads in *Java*. So this documentation talks about the actual *Java* `Thread`. And a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) just manages several threads.

> Most of the executor implementations in java.util.concurrent use thread pools, which consist of worker threads. This kind of thread exists separately from the Runnable and Callable tasks it executes and is often used to execute multiple tasks.

Comment: I am pretty new to the topic. So you mean `Dispatchers.IO` will have all native IO threads in the pool? If yes then what is the advantage we are getting here in coroutines?

Comment: There's nothing like that. It's just a collection of threads only used by `Dispatchers.IO`. The exact properties of the managment I'm not sure about. The advantage of coroutines is, that it's a lightweight and extensive framework for async programming.